# Ruby: check if a string is formatted in a very specific way

Tags: ruby, regex, string, match, geometry

I'm trying to write a piece of code that tells the user if a string is formatted in a specific way. The format looks like this (it's a circle):

```
     ######\n
  ###      ###\n
 #            #\n
#              #\n
#              #\n
#              #\n
 #            #\n
  ###      ###\n
     ######\n
\n
```

The newlines are included for clarity; the # character may be any character from an existing character class.

What I want to do is check if a string (from a file) contains one or more of these "circles". Multiple circles should be seperated like this:

```
#            #\n
 ###      ###\n
    ######\n
\n
    ######\n
 ###      ###\n
#            #\n
```

So this is what I've tried:

```
isCircle = "(     #{get_i}{6}\n"
isCircle += "  #{get_i}{3}       #{get_i}{3}\n"
isCircle += " #{get_i}             #{get_i}\n"
isCircle +=("#{get_i}               #{get_i}\n"*3)
isCircle += " #{get_i}             #{get_i}\n"
isCircle += "  #{get_i}{3}       #{get_i}{3}\n"
isCircle = "     #{get_i}{6}\n\n?)*"

isCircle = Regexp.new(isCircle)
```

(get_i is a method that returns the aforementioned character class, correctly escaped and everything)

However, when testing this against an incorrect input string, it still tells me there's a match.
What am I doing wrong and how can I correctly perform the match?

Comment: A regex is probably not the best way to handle this.

Comment: @Amal Murali Then what is?

Comment: Why don't you just look for the specific string `"     ######\n..."` in the file? Your pattern is a constant so basic string operations should be sufficient, no?

Comment: Your regexp matches 0 or more occurrences of your circle (the * at the end) so it will always find a match (possibly a 0 length one)

Comment: @muistooshort I think I'll do that. All regex based solutions made the program look too complex.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
[ ]+#{6}[\n ]+#{3}[ ]+#{3}[\n ]+(?>#[ ]+#[\n\s]+)+#{3}[ ]+#{3}[\n\s]+#{6}\s*
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/rZ75f9dMo4)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?

Suppose you wish to search for this pattern:

```
pattern = 
%{     ######
  ###      ###
 #            #
#              #
#              #
#              #
 #            #
  ###      ###
     ######
}
```

in a text file whose contents have been read into this string:

```
str =
 %{###
  ##
     ######
  ###      ###
 #            #
#              #
#              #
#              #
 #            #
  ###      ###
     ######
     #######
######
     ######
  ###      ###
 #            #
#              #
#              #
#              #
 #            #
  ###      ###
     ######
  ###
}
```

Just use [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
puts str.scan(pattern).join("\n")
     ######
  ###      ###
 #            #
#              #
#              #
#              #
 #            #
  ###      ###
     ######

     ######
  ###      ###
 #            #
#              #
#              #
#              #
 #            #
  ###      ###
     ######
```

If you instead want the line offsets of `str` where the pattern begins:

```
sarr  = str.lines
parr  = pattern.lines
prows = parr.size
(sarr.size-prows+1).times.select { |i| sarr[i,prows] == parr }
  #==> [2, 13]
```